# A website URL is not loading with Curl php

Tags: php, curl, ip

I am using Curl PHP to fetch data from remote site. My Script is:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.(url).com/';

$sleep = rand(10, 12);

sleep($sleep);

$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8','accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch','accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "x.x.x.x:x");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

$mainPage = new simple_html_dom;

echo $mainPage->load($result);
```

But it returns `403 forbidden` error in response.

I tried with advanced User agents include, but still I am getting this error in response.

Thanks in advance for suggestions and comments.

Comment: I am afraid we cannot tell you why some specific site returns a 403 status code in a specific situation. This is up to whoever operates that site...

Comment: I am just trying to scrap the public data from a remote site.

Comment: @BalamuruganV - Link of this site ?